# Getting a particular data from instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying to make a shopping cart in Laravel, and I am still a learner.

In the cart, I am trying to print details of products present in the cart, along with their quantity.

The details of several products of cart is present in `$prod`, while quantity is present in `$cart`. I am running a `foreach` to access each product of the cart, as well as its quantity.

In an explanatory way, I am trying to do this:

```
@foreach( $prod as $p )
    <td>Quantity = {{ $cart[ "product_id" == $p->id]->quantity }}<td>
@endforeach
```

I am trying to match the `$p->id`, the details which I am printing, to the quantity in `$cart` as `$cart` has it under `product_id` attribute in table.

I am sorry if I am unable to explain the question the right way.

Thank you.

Comment: Show tables structure your have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solutions assumes you are using Eloquent Models, if you are not you should. On your `Product.php` model, define the relationship.

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function cart()
    {
        // Laravel automatically know to look in carts table for an product_id column
        return $this->belongsTo(Cart::class);
    }
}
```

Now you have a relationship method for your cart, this is useful if you want to save it. For just loading it out of the database, if you access `$product->cart` it will automatically fetch the `Cart.php` model. So you can quite simply write.

```
@foreach( $prod as $p )
    <td>Quantity = {{ $p->cart->quantity }}<td>
@endforeach
```